# How do I make a tiled background on a tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a small image file that I would like to make as the tiled background image on a tkinter canvas in Python 3.4. I want the image to repeat indefinitely even if the canvas window is resized. How can I go about implementing this?

Looking around on the internet leads me to believe that there isn't any native tkinter feature for doing this simply. Is there any "black-box" method in an image library that can interface with tkinter for doing this tiling? Or should I manually render copies of the image at regularly spaced coordinates?

Comment: i think you are going to have to manually add them at regular coordinates and then bind to the <<Configure>> event to add more when the canvas is resized

Comment: A tkinter canvas can be larger than the window.  If you fix in size, I would tile the whole canvas rather than just the visible part.